# Unable to display relatedlist in visual force email template

Tags: email, email-template, visualforce-template

Hi in the below visualforce code i am unable to display orderItem related list  .the custom related list object orderItem is a managed package, to show the related list i have taken the masterdetail relationship field's Child Relationship Name 'E_OrderItems' and refer to it as "E_OrderItems__r" in the template. but i am getting error like    "Error: Invalid field E_OrderItems__r for SObject ccrz__E_Order__c"

Required immediate assistance in this regard ,Advance Thanks

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Order Update Confirmation" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="ccrz__E_Order__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color:#2F2F2F;
}

table {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid;
    
    webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

th{
    color: #0d6bab;
    font-family: ProximaNovaBold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>

    <html>

            <body>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>{!relatedTo.Name} placed an order. Current order status is: Order Submitted</th>    
                </tr>
                <tr><th style="text-align: left">Order Number :{!relatedTo.SAP_Order_Number__c}</th></tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding-bottom: 20px;width:450px; text-align: left;">Billing and Shipping Address</th>  
                         
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <th style="color:#000;width:100px; text-align: left;font-size: 13px; ">Bill To  </th>
                    <th style="color:#000;width:100px;font-size: 13px;padding-right: 50px;">Ship to</th>
                     
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="color:#000;width:100px; text-align: left; ">{!relatedTo.SAP_Order_Number__c} </td>
                    <td style="color:#000;width:100px;padding-right: 50px;font-size: 13px;">text</td>
                     
                </tr>
            </table>
           
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order Items</th>    
                </tr>
                <br/>
                <tr>
                    <th style="color:#000;width:100px;">Product</th>
                    <th style="color:#000;width:100px;">Price</th>
                    <th style="color:#000;width:100px;">Qty</th>
                    <th style="color:#000;width:100px;">Total</th>    
                </tr>
                 <apex:repeat var="noteToDis" value="{!relatedTo.E_OrderItems__r}">
              <tr>
                 <td >{!noteToDis.ccrz__Product_Name__c}</td>
                <td >{!noteToDis.ccrz__Price__c)} </td>
                
              
                <td >{!noteToDis.ccrz__Quantity__c} </td>
                <td >{!noteToDis.ccrz__ItemTotal__c)}</td>
              </tr>
          </apex:repeat>    
            </table>
            <br/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Totals</th>    
                </tr>
            </table>
           
            </body>

        </html>

    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a managed package, presumably the child list is also part of the managed package

Thus, your `apex:repeat` needs to namesapce the relationship name

You have:

```
<apex:repeat var="noteToDis" value="{!relatedTo.E_OrderItems__r}">
```

You need:

```
<apex:repeat var="noteToDis" value="{!relatedTo.ccrz__E_OrderItems__r}">
```

*PS: Community etiquette discourages appeals for `immediate assistance`*